# How to append the data in the log file when the batch file is executed

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wanted to append the contents of the log file when i ran batch file often, code im using in batch file to create a log file which contains data present in the console is 
call test1.bat >logfile.log 2>&1 This only create the log file once and will not delete or append the data in the log file..
Please help me out to solve this issue.
this is the content of the file

```
@echo off
CD /D %~dp0
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "data=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%"
echo Yesterday was "%data%"

set year=%data:~0,4%
set month=%date:~4,2%
set day=%data:~8,3%

set filename=Login_%year%-%month%-%day%.log.gz

echo Filename =  %filename%


C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\php.exe  C:\wamp\www\F\csv\index.php 
call test1.bat >>logfile.log 2>&1


pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
call test1.bat >>logfile.log 2>&1
```

Like in every shell `>>` is for appending.Check also [this](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Comment: @ npocmaka    will try and let you know

Comment: @ npocmaka the contents are getting appended when I close the console and run the batch file.when I try to run the same batch with the console opened the contents are not getting appended why I dont know? Does console gets closed after few minutes ?any idea

Comment: @happy - with what command you are running your bat and what is the content of the bat? Are there redirections in the bat?

Comment: @npocmaka-Have edited the question please see Im not using any command to run ,running it directly and will ran as cron job later

Comment: @npocmaka-Okay now im running batch file as cron job and checking whether the data is getting appended in the logfile

Comment: @npocmaka-I ran the batch file as cron job,the contents are getting appended because I have opened the previous executed consoles in my system.Once i close the console and data is getting inserted.I wanted to close console after it is executed how to do that.Then only the contents gets appended